# How could I continue asking questions on Mathematics Stack Exchange?

Tags: support

I asked seven questions during two and and a half years of my account on Mathematics Stack Exchange. Before I raised each of them, I was researching the topic for tens or even for hundreds of hours. Unfortunatelly, I have noticed this day that I cannot ask questions anymore.

I do not want to working on improvements of my previous questions as recommended because these questions are not relevant for me anymore. On the other hand, I wish to have an opportunity to ask questions about new or at least updated topics after I have continued reserching and made some progress which understanding I would like to check.

Could you please help?

Comment: You can either attempt to improve the questions you have already asked (including *deleted* questions), or you can post a new question once every 6 months, and hope that it is better recieved.